# Unable to find the strategy to implement constraints, keys, indexes while loading tables

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I want to create one Generic pipeline in ADF which covers below scenario.

Pipeline should accept two input parameters :
Source Table name
Sink Table name

Pipeline should execute below way.

1. Connect to source
2. Identify the source table fields and data types and create the table with the given name in the sink
3. Data should copied to sink.
4. Pipeline should handle indexes, keys and constraints.

For above requirement i created a lookup which fetches table list names from a csv file. Lookup is followed by Foreach activity which have a copy activity inside it. Now i am able to create tables from list of tables and also copy the data. But unable to handle indexes, keys and constraints(refer point 4). Can someone help how to achieve this.

Comment: ... with how much you want copied, you're essentially backing up/restoring tables (minus triggers and maybe a few other things), which might be easier to do (although there might be issues with renaming tables/schemas).  Maybe I just don't know your problem space, but to me it feels strange to copy tables this way, especially as part of an automated system.  Can you describe _why_ you're doing this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i wanted to create a generic pipeline which will take table names as input and then copy the whole table as it is to some other schema/db. since we are retiring current system need this automation to get implemented.

Comment: There are existing tools for data migration, using replication, or just backup/restore-ing the database is the normal way to "copy" a database, because usually you only migrate table definitions _once_ (and usually in one go).  If your goal is to move from on-prem to a cloud database, what you're going for here is overkill.  [There are guides for this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/database-migration/) - would this be what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve 1,2,3 steps with parameters and other actives. But Data Factory doesn't support move or copy the indexes keys and constraints.

We can't achieve that in Data factory, it's more focus on the data moving. Even with auto create table, we need manually create the indexes, keys and constraints in the sink database.

Comment: Can we write a script in notebook to achieve 4th point and invoke that in our pipeline? Do you have any idea regarding script to achieve results for 4th point?

Comment: @Sameera the indexes, keys and constraints only can be created after the table created. You could call the notebook after the foreach actives succeed, I'm sorry that I have no idea about how to write the script for you and not sure if the script could works. You could try this way.

Comment: can you help on these point with respect to ADF part? 
1. If destination table exists, does it overwrites ?
2. If data already exists does it truncates and loads ? how to handle these points in pipeline.

Comment: @Sameera I mean once the 1,2,3 steps finished, the table is exist and just run the script as step 4 to create the keys indexes and constraints. For example as you said in problem description, lookup+foreach+notebook to constitute the pipeline.